# Java/ Sum of any two values in an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sum, combinations, equals

I have a task:
Write code that will have an array of valuesTable and givenNumber from integer. The method will list the number of such combinations that the sum of any two
elements in the array equal to the number stored in givenNumber.

Should I make another array to storage sum of any two elements?
What kind of method use to get the sum of any two elements in the array?
How list the number of combinations?

I would be very grateful for your help, this is my first steps in Java :)

```
public class NumberOfCombinations {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] valuesTable = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int givenNumber = 3;
    int index=0;
    int sum = 0;
    int n = valuesTable.length;
    for (index = 0; index < n; index++)
        sum = valuesTable[index] + valuesTable[++index];

    }


}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Please provide what you have done so far, and then ask for advice. Coding is spending a lot of time banging your head to find a solution, then the simple part is implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Should I make another array to storage sum of any two elements?*

If it is required to provide only the number of the pairs equal to the given number, array is not required, simple `if` statement allows to check the condition and increment the counter (and print the pair if needed):

```java
if (a[i] + a[j] == x) {
    pairs++;
    System.out.println("Found a pair: " + a[i] + " + " + a[j]);
}
```

> *What kind of method use to get the sum of any two elements in the array?*

Two nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
//...
    }
}
```

> *How list the number of combinations?*

The total number of possible pairs is calculated by the formula of decreasing progression from n - 1 to 1: `S = n * (n - 1) / 2`, so for n = 5 it is `5 * 4 / 2 = 10`.

The number of matching pairs is simply counted in the innermost loop.